# SQL Query much slower from Linq than directly from management Studio

Tags: sql-server, performance, linq

I'm experiencing a very strange performance issue when executing a query through C# Linq to SQL. Usually the query takes a second or two to execute, but for some very specific search criteria the query suddenly takes more than a minute to run through Linq to SQL but still only 2 seconds in SQL Management Studio.

**The query:**

The query resulting from the Linq to SQL lookup is the rather complex structure shown below. TV_TRACKER_ORDER is a view that merges data from more than 10 tables.

```
DECLARE @p0 Int; SET @p0 = '4';
DECLARE @p1 Int; SET @p1 = '666685';
DECLARE @p2 DateTime; SET @p2 = '2/1/2013 12:00:00 AM';
DECLARE @p3 DateTime; SET @p3 = '5/23/2013 12:00:00 AM';

SELECT [t0].[HAULIER], [t0].[G_NUMBER], [t0].[CUST_ORDER_REF], [t0].[CUSTOMER], [t0].[RELEASE_NO], [t0].[BILL_OF_LADEN], [t0].[TERMINAL], [t0].[PRODUCT], [t0].[SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_DATE], [t0].[DRIVER], [t0].[TRACTOR], [t0].[TRAILER], [t0].[STATE], [t0].[DRIVER_NAME], [t0].[HOME_DEPOT], [t0].[TRACTOR_NAME], [t0].[TRAILER_NAME], [t0].[CUSTOMER_NAME], [t0].[TERMINAL_NAME], [t0].[STATE_NAME], [t0].[Shift], [t0].[SHIFT_NAME], [t0].[HOME_DEPOT_NAME], [t0].[DELIVERY_LOCATION], [t0].[DELIVERY_LOCATION_NAME], [t0].[SYSTEM_REMAINDER_RESOLUTION]
FROM [dbo].[TV_TRACKER_ORDER] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (50) [t2].[G_NUMBER]
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[G_NUMBER]
            FROM [dbo].[TV_TRACKER_ORDER] AS [t1]
            WHERE ([t1].[STATE] = (CONVERT(Decimal(29,4),@p0))) AND ([t1].[HAULIER] = (CONVERT(Decimal(29,4),@p1))) AND ((@p2) <= [t1].[SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_DATE]) AND ([t1].[SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_DATE] <= (@p3))
            ) AS [t2]
        ORDER BY [t2].[G_NUMBER]
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[G_NUMBER] = [t0].[G_NUMBER]
    )
ORDER BY [t0].[G_NUMBER]
```

**What I have Tried:**

- If I change TOP 50 to TOP 49 or to TOP 51 the query only takes a few seconds to run (without the TOP  entry, the query returns 10121 rows in 1841 groups).
- If I set the start time (@p2) to a year before, the query also completes in a few seconds.
- Using SQL Server management Studio Activity Monitor I can see that the bad query DO in fact run for more than a minute, and i can see the SQL that is run matches what I have shown above.

**Help**

I'm completely at a loss on how to proceed with this.

- How come the query runs fast on SQL Server Management Studio, but extremely slow through Linq?
- How come it runs 30 times faster on Linq (as fast as on Management Studio) if i extract a few more records from the query (changes TOP 50 to TOP 51)?

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently the performance issue was caused by problems with the query optimization statistics on the database. Running "exec sp_updatestats" fixed the problem (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173804.aspx)

Comment: I was just going to suggest statistics as a reasonable first attempt. Add that as an answer and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
DECLARE 
      @p0 INT
    , @p1 INT
    , @p2 DATETIME
    , @p3 DATETIME

SELECT 
      @p0 = 4
    , @p1 = 666685
    , @p2 = '20130201 12:00:00'
    , @p3 = '20130523 12:00:00'

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TV_TRACKER_ORDER t0
WHERE t0.[STATE] = @p0
    AND t0.HAULIER = @p1
    AND @p2 <= t0.SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_DATE 
    AND t0.SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_DATE <= @p3
ORDER BY t0.G_NUMBER
```

Comment: Really, you don't need `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeking an optimization of my query (I am stuck with what Linq to SQL makes for me). Besides the query performs acceptable in all other situations.